# Given notice period and left without job offer

Tags: job-offer, notice-period

Recently I left a job with 2 months notice period without getting a job offer. The reason I left was because I had not been paid my salary for 3 consecutive months. During this notice period I was unable to find a job and now as my notice period is completed still find myself without an offer.

However, I have started getting calls from reputed companies who are asking me how many days of notice period I have and if I have any job offer. I am unsure how to respond to these questions as I am unsure of the intentions of the questions. Why might they be interested in these factors and how should I respond?

Comment: There is no way we can possibly answer this question.  Giving notice for a job before you find another will always lead to the very real possibility of finding yourself jobless.  If you aren't being paid by your current employer, then there should have been statutory protections in place for you.  As far as the reputable companies, are they offering you interviews or just cold calling?  Unless you have a role description and an application process, they don't mean anything.

Comment: Hi Naseer welcome to the Workplace! I edited your question to try to make it more along the guidelines of The Workplace, however I might have lost the original intention behind the question. If my edit was different than what you were asking please [edit](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/posts/44808/edit) it to make it clear what you are asking!

Comment: If someone asks how many days notice you have to give, you say "I'm available immediately". If they ask if you have a job offer you answer truthfully. What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when these reputed companies ask you how many days of notice you have, you have two options:

1. Tell the truth - "I am available to start immediately!"
2. Lie about still being in work and make up some date when you will supposedly be
   available

Now, if you read questions about interviewing on this site, you will find wide agreement that it is a really, *really* bad idea to lie in a job interview. What do you think is going to happen if you lie and they find out (because people know people) that actually you are no longer working at the company you claim to be working at? That actually you quit months ago?

You've just lost any opportunity to be hired, I'd say.

Now, you may be worried that some employers have a prejudice in favour of hiring people who are currently in work, rather than people who are currently unemployed. This is probably true, it's unfortunate, it can't really be helped. *Telling the truth may hurt some of your prospects.* But lying is much more risky.

Also, bear in mind that your immediate availability is a positive factor. I don't know what country you're in, but if two month notice periods are standard there, then the fact that you can start immediately rather than in two months time is an *even bigger positive*. Sell yourself. When they ask what your notice period is, tell them that not only are you available immediately but that you're super excited by the prospect of joining their awesome team immediately!

As for your second question, if one potential employer asks if you have any other job offers? That's a question which, regardless of your circumstances, you should be polite but non-committal about. Tell them that you are talking to various companies but do not say that you do or do not have any firm offers. That's really none of their business.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about your notice period and other job offers are not trick questions. These are standard questions companies ask to obtain information essential for their decision on your candidature.

You don't need to get worried or think too much about it. Just state the facts, like so:

> **Q**: What's your notice period?
>   **A**: I can join immediately. 
>   **Q**: Do you have any other offers?
>   **A**: No, not yet. I am searching for job.

Nobody really cares what your notice period was with your previous company, what they really want to know is how soon you could join them.

Some curious people will ask (unnecessarily) why you resigned before you got another job offer. Resist the temptation to badmouth your previous employer. Just respond with some obscure reason like, "Due to certain personal circumstances, I had to end that job. Now I want to get a new job again."

The irony is that hiring managers tend to prefer people already holding jobs rather than unemployed people (all other things being equal, of course). However, people being unemployed between jobs is not a huge shocking incident that occurs once in a millennium, so it won't be that big of an issue by itself.